# Qt 4.8.2. Qt Crearor выдает ошибки

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

начал изучать Qt. Преподаватель дал готовый код калькулятора на 4.8.2  сказал скопировать и разобрать его. Скопировал — QtCreator начал материться. В чем проблема и как ее исправить? Спасибо.

Вот код соответствующих файлов и скриншоты ошибок QtCreator

файл Calculator.cpp

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "Calculator.h"

Calculator::Calculator(QWidget* pwgt/*= 0*/) : QWidget(pwgt)
{
m_plcd = new QLCDNumber(12);
m_plcd->setSegmentStyle(QLCDNumber::Flat);
m_plcd->setMinimumSize(150, 50);

QChar aButtons[4][4] = {{'7', '8', '9', '/'},
                        {'4', '5', '6', '*'},
                        {'1', '2', '3', '-'},
                        {'0', '.', '=', '+'}
                       };

//Layout setup
QGridLayout* ptopLayout = new QGridLayout;
ptopLayout->addWidget(m_plcd, 0, 0, 1, 4);
ptopLayout->addWidget(createButton("CE"), 1, 3);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
       ptopLayout->addWidget(createButton(aButtons[i][j]), i + 2, j);
    }
}
setLayout(ptopLayout);
}
QPushButton* Calculator::createButton(const QString& str)
{
QPushButton* pcmd = new QPushButton(str);
pcmd->setMinimumSize(40, 40);
connect(pcmd, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(slotButtonClicked()));
return pcmd;
}


void Calculator::calculate()
{
double  dOperand2    = m_stk.pop().toDouble();
QString strOperation = m_stk.pop();
double  dOperand1    = m_stk.pop().toDouble();
double  dResult      = 0;

if (strOperation == "+") {
    dResult = dOperand1 + dOperand2;
}
if (strOperation == "-") {
    dResult = dOperand1 - dOperand2;
}
if (strOperation == "/") {
    dResult = dOperand1 / dOperand2;
}
if (strOperation == "*") {
    dResult = dOperand1 * dOperand2;
}
m_plcd->display(dResult);
}

void Calculator::slotButtonClicked()
{
QString str = ((QPushButton*)sender())->text();

if (str == "CE") {
    m_stk.clear();
    m_strDisplay = "";
    m_plcd->display("0");
    return;
}
if (str.contains(QRegExp("[0-9]"))) {
    m_strDisplay += str;
    m_plcd->display(m_strDisplay.toDouble());
}
else if (str == ".") {
    m_strDisplay += str;
    m_plcd->display(m_strDisplay);
}
else {
    if (m_stk.count() >= 2) {
        m_stk.push(QString().setNum(m_plcd->value()));
        calculate();
        m_stk.clear();
        m_stk.push(QString().setNum(m_plcd->value()));
        if (str != "=") {
            m_stk.push(str);
        }
    }
    else {
        m_stk.push(QString().setNum(m_plcd->value()));
        m_stk.push(str);

        m_strDisplay = "";
        m_plcd->display("0");
    }
}
}
```

Скриншоты с ошибками файла Calculator.cpp
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл Calculator.h

```
#ifndef _Calculator_h_
#define _Calculator_h_

#include <QWidget>
#include <QStack>

class QLCDNumber;
class QPushButton;
class Calculator : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  private:
  QLCDNumber*     m_plcd;
  QStack<QString> m_stk;
  QString         m_strDisplay;

  public:
  Calculator(QWidget* pwgt = 0);

  QPushButton* createButton(const QString& str);
  void         calculate   (                  );

  public slots:
  void slotButtonClicked();
  };

  #endif  //_Calculator_h_
```

Скриншоты с ошибками файла Calculator.h

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файл Calculator.pro

```
 TEMPLATE     = app
 HEADERS         = Calculator.h
 SOURCES         = Calculator.cpp main.cpp
 win32:TARGET = ../Calculator
```

Возможно проблема в win32:TARGET У меня Х64 и если я правильно понял в этой строке путь к проекту нужен?

Файл main.cpp

```
 #include <QApplication>
 #include "Calculator.h"

 int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
QApplication app(argc, argv);
Calculator   calculator;

calculator.setWindowTitle("Calculator");
calculator.resize(230, 200);

calculator.show();

return app.exec();
}
```

Скриншот с ошибками
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибки при сборке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Страница проекты
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сриншот, после добавления 4.8.2 
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Связанный вопрос с ошибкой после сборки  [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/942193/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-qt-untested-windows-version-6-2-detected?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: надо отключить (пока), всё что касается clang, в меню `Help/About plugins ...`, в Filter ввести clang, всё выключить и перезагрузить creator

Comment: @PavelGridin помогло спасибо. А что я отключил?))

Comment: @PavelGridin Теперь ошибки при сборке возникли

Comment: меня одного смущает что там на скринах Qt 5.1 а в заголовке вопроса 4.8.2 ? Или это особенности QtCreator под Windows ? Или вообще не важно важно что в комплекте правильная версия выбрана ?

Comment: @Konstantin_SH, это статический анализатор, пытается угадать ошибки до компиляции, не всегда правильно работает

Comment: @vegorov Я скачивал Qt 4.8.2 отдельно. Добавил соответствующий профиль в шаблон Desctop и создал проект на 4.8.2

Comment: Ну тогда всё ок наверное =) Ошибки то добавили, которые при сборке возникли ?

Comment: @vegorov сейчас добавлю

Comment: @vegorov готово

Comment: Скорее всего неправильно проект сконфигурирован, что на странице `Проекты`?

Comment: Или вы показали не весь файл .pro, или косяк в нем. Не хватает `qt += core gui` и дальше по обстоятельствам

Comment: @PavelGridin добавил страницу проекты

Comment: Там же написано Qt5_1. Везде. Почему Вы уверены что это Qt 4.8.2 ?

Comment: creator не видит qt4.8.2, надо добавить в `Tools/Options/Kits` и сконфигурить проект с Qt4.8.2, https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-targets.html

Comment: Понял, сейчас попробую

Comment: Выдает предупреждение. Добавляю скриншот