# Ошибка Qt. Untested Windows version 6.2 detected

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Программа пытается запуститься, но не запускается. Компилируется с предупреждением что не тестировалось в Windows 8, но у меня 10. Версия Qt 4.8.2 Прикрепляю скрин с ошибкой.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Весь код в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/942124/qt-4-8-2-qt-crearor-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8/942141?noredirect=1#comment1566998_942141) вопросе если нужно.

Скриншот переменной PATH
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запустил exe из ОС
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Untested Windows version 6.2 detected` - не обращайте внимания это qmake пишет, причина не в этом, возможно не видит Qt-dll

Comment: @PavelGridin Переустановка Qt поможет?

Comment: Может вам проще будет поставить виртуалку, там поднять Ubuntu какую-нибудь, пакет build-essential, пакет с qt 4.8, и скачать qtcreator ? И всё сразу заработает

Comment: @Konstantin_SH, не надо переустанавливать, попробуйте поставить в PATH путь с dll, это где qmake лежит, если не пойдёт запустите из винды, что напишет? Только Qt-путь в PATH ставьте впереди, бывает, что в системе мешают qt-dll от других программ

Comment: @PavelGridin Поменял через Windows панель управления. Все та же ошибка. Вот скрин.

Comment: @PavelGridin Запустил программу из Windows, написало это

Comment: Так, а где вы взяли gcc 4.4 ? Qt 4.8.2 требует mingw c gcc 4.4

Comment: У меня 7 MinGW. Сейчас попробую скачать

Comment: Не не. Вы не поняли. Там нужен именно тот mingw, с которым собирался qt 4.8.2 из архива.

Comment: @vegorov а где его искать в папках с qt? я ставил галочку на установку Min'GW

Comment: @vegorov у меня просто видит только компиляторы из папки с 5 qt, Хочу попробовать добавить вручную.

Comment: Так погодите. Я вот щас скачал 4.8.2 с архива, начал установку. В процессе установки вас спрашивают где находится mingw с gcc 4.4 - вы указываете папку. И если что-то пошло не так Вас предупреждают. У Вас было предупреждение ?

Comment: Открыл установщик заново. Да есть предупреждение. Все понял пошел устанавливать.

Comment: [раз](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-26137), [два](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-26137?focusedCommentId=188642&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-188642). Я погуглил название архива, что там указывается, скачал, разахивировал в папку, указал эту папку установщику - он предупреждений не выдал. Щас дотесчю отпишусь, чтоб вы всякой с интернетов не  качали

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное.

Comment: Ну собственно да, если погуглить и скачать `MinGW-gcc440_1.zip`, использовать его при установке Qt 4.8.2, то у Вас он поставится. После чего в новом QtCreator вы сможете добавить новый профиль qt4.8.2 и добавить компиляторы из gcc4.4.1. НО!!! У меня в QtCreator 4.7.0, который видимо заточен под Qt5.9+, нельзя создать приложение Qt Widgets с новым комплектом 4.8.2. Более того, у меня получилось создать только обычно пустое приложение qmake, с одним MainWindow. Но там нет подсветки а автодополнения, и я не знаю как настроить последний QtCreator чтобы он подружился с древним qt4.8.2

Comment: То есть под Windows вам ещё и QtCreator старый надо поставить

Comment: Я попробовал QtCreator 2.6.2 - завелось. И подсветка есть, и собирается и запускается. Главное комплект настроить. И у меня Windows-7

Comment: @vegorov Скачал MinGW 4,4 Завелось пока, спасибо.